# Running jQuery from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What I'm trying to accomplish is to call a PHP page with an ajax request when an object is clicked and from the PHP page some jQuery will be returned that will determine whether to fade or not to fade the object.

Here is the code returned by the PHP page if the object should be removed:

```
$attr = '#all'.$numAttr;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
        $("'.$attr.'").fadeOut();
        });
    });
        </script>';
```

Here is the jQuery code with the ajax request:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
$(".item").click(function() {
    var attrID = $(this).attr('id');
    var attrNum = attrID.substring(5)
    var itemID2 = $(testAttr).html();
    var id2 = $(testAttr+"p").html();
$.get( "http://www.refaim.com/use", {itemID: ""+itemID2, id: "" + id2, numAttr: attrNum}, function( data ) {
$(".action").html(( data ));
});
});
```

});

Edit: Can't believe I forgot to include why I submitted this question. My problem is that the jQuery loaded from the PHP page into a div is not working, the object does not fade when it's clicked.

Comment: and problem is ? do we have to guess it ?

Comment: Why not you put the fadeOut code in jquery success function?

Comment: 1) it's bad practice to send scripts through AJAX. It's better to include all neccessary code with the initial load. 2) `live` is now removed from jQuery. You better stop using it already. And 3) no, that's not how you use it (or used to use it when it was still alive).

Comment: @JanDvorak The problem with that is that the object clicked by the user might not have to be faded and the only way to determine that is by calling another PHP script. Is there another way to take the result of the PHP script and then update the jQuery based on that?
The live was a mistake, I changed it to ready.

Comment: @ZahidulHosseinRipon can I return a value from the PHP script that will determine whether the script is a success or not? Last I read about the success function is that it runs if the ajax call was successful, not based on what's returned by the PHP script.

Comment: @pr1nc3 I'm sorry, I edited my post. Sorry about that, don't know how I wanted you to read my mind.

Comment: @user2243125 you should send back a boolean variable, which the client side would read. If you want to send multiple pieces of data, wrap that in a JSON object. Look up `$.ajax` and the shorthands `$.get` and `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ajax success function you can put your fadeout code depending the value is return from your php file

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "yourphppage.php",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(msg){            
 if(msg=='your return value')
 //then do fadeOut here
 }
}); //END $.ajax
```

Comment: What is the msg variable in the function? Is that supposed to be the data returned by the request, which is dataString? Just trying to understand what's happening before using the code, I like to learn rather copy and paste.

Comment: `success:function(msg)` is the data returned by your PHP page.

Comment: msg is the variable which take the return value by your php page

Comment: @ZahidulHosseinRipon Thank you, I used your idea and indexOf to check for a specific key word. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

function(data) is the value returned by your PHP. you can add if statement right after the call.

```
$.get( "http://www.refaim.com/use", {
       itemID: ""+itemID2,
       id: "" + id2, 
       numAttr: attrNum}, 
     function( data ) {
     if(data == 'something') {
        $('<your html element>').fadeOut();
     }
});
});
```